# Azure DevOps - permissions issue with deployment groups

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Does anyone know where I can set the permission to manage deployment groups in Azure DevOps.

If i click on "deployment groups" in the menu shown here:

[image]

I am receiving this message when i click on a deployment group.

[image]

The error message states:

> You do not have permissions to register targets. Contact your release
>   manager to grant permission

I am a member of both project administrators and build administrators groups.

Comment: What are your agent pool permissions? A deployment group is a special kind of agent pool.

Comment: If i go to agent pools  by going to organization settings->agent pools and i click "security" i receive another message "You do not have permissions to edit roles for this resource"

Comment: There you go. You need to be granted permission to manage agent pools.

Comment: I totally agree  but do you happen to know where this permission is located? i do not see this permission available anywhere.

Comment: What do your permissions show in: ```https://dev.azure.com/{your-organization-name}/_settings/deploymentpools?view=pools```

Comment: I added myself to build administrators, logged out and logged back in and i am able to see the agent pool security now.  I thought this would solve my issue with the deployment group but it does not.

Comment: @m00nbeam360.0 it shows "you do not have permission to manage this deployment pool's roles"

Comment: Are you able to go into a specific deployment group from that page and grant yourself Admin permissions to one of them? This also might help: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/339688/deployment-group-permissions-error.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem and solve it with the following permission settings.

Click **Manage** in the Deployment pool

[image]

If you get this error `you do not have permission to manage this deployment pool's roles` to prevent you from modifying permissions in Security. You need to be added to **Project Collection Administrators** group in organization setting permissions. If you can't be added to the PCA group, you can let the users in the PCA group help you modify it.

[image]

Set the user's Role to **Administrator** in Security, click `Save Changes`.

[image]

After this setting, you will not receive the error message:`You do not have permissions to register targets. Contact your release manager to grant permission` when you enter the Deployment groups.

Comment: We were discussing this yesterday internal here that we also believe this is the issue because one of our developers who setup our azure project is in that group and that is the only security difference we see.   I will confirm this and accept this as the answer if it proves out.  thank you

Comment: confirmed as a fix.  Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

This access is not required as I was able to fix this without changing org level access to others and indeed such access is not made to share with all.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31273381)